# Cannot cast from Loader<Object> to CursorLoader

Tags: android

I want to get the initialized `CursorLoader` instance from `LoaderManager` like this:

```
CursorLoader loader = (CursorLoader) getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

```
Cannot cast from Loader<Object> to CursorLoader
```

I could hold the `CursorLoader` instance when it is created, but I'd rather let `LoaderManager` maintain it. So any idea to fix this?

I am using compatibility-library-v4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It needs to be converted twice:

```
Loader<Cursor> loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
CursorLoader cloader = (CursorLoader) loader;
```

Comment: How would you do the opposite?  I'm trying to build a loader which can create a CursorLoader or MyAsyncTaskLoader.  How do you change the CursorLoader into a Loader<Object>, or is there a different way.

Comment: `CursorLoader` is the child of `Loader<Object>`, you could directly assign `CursorLoader` to `Loader<Object>` or `Loader<Cursor>`.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of the format, tried all the casting I know but it won't work.  In a similar post someone suggested returning Loader<? extends Object> but sadly this didn't work either.